# Nvidia Drivers question

Tags: graphic-drivers

I recently bought a new computer and was looking at the different linux  distributions and this one got me right away (my prev is a Macbook and the os is pretty similar).

I installed the drivers using the terminal and the version is 367, but when I go to the nvidia website I see unix drivers version 375. Is this normal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,it's completely normal.

The propietary NVIDIA drivers go trough a process that starts from the NVIDIA devs and ends on the Ubuntu/elementaryOS repos. The version available on the NVIDIA website is not a stable version so you would need to wait a bit more to use that one.

Usually it's safe to install any version from the Ubuntu repositories. Those have already been tested so they should work. You are using the 367 version because that's been tested already but there's a newer one (375) that hasn't been tested so installing it may break your system.